# How to stop a query from executing and return 'failed'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL plugin. My need is to stop the query search and return a `failed` message to the web page when the plugin finds a special char — let's say '$' — in the query.

code: https://github.com/sreelakshmy/mysql-plugin/blob/master/trial.c

My query sample :

```
   SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$pswd';
```

If I try to execute this the plugin should stop the execution and return failed to access.

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Do I understand you, you want to check the user or some other input for special characters? If so you could use regex/pattern matching to check for certain ones and return failed if that is the case. Or you could just escape the input so that the query doesnt need to fail.

Comment: ya i'm checking for some special char and return failed if those are found. not just escape the input but fail the query

Comment: means you want to retrun false if any error occured?

Comment: yes i want to return false if a special char is found

Comment: Doing this with a plugin seems like the hard way, not to mention the fact that you are apparently storing passwords unencrypted. (!?)  This is really more appropriately handled by the application, not MySQL.  Is there a reason you're taking this particular approach?